# WCF test client no longer works in Visual Studio 2013 but does work in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am running both visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2015.  I can't say when it started but most recently I was trying to debug a wcf service application in Visual Studio 2013 and the wcf test client will not launch.  Instead, it launches a webpage with the localhost url.  I tried creating a clean, new wcf project with the template IService and Service.svc only to have the same thing happen.  However, when I go over to my different WCF project in Visual Studio 2015, the WCF client tool launches just fine when I press F5.

I have had 2015 installed for a while, and am fairly positive I have run the WCF client tool from 2013 just fine.  In any event, I am not sure why it isn't working in 2013 nor how to get it to work.  suggestions?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: When it shows the web page at the url http://localhost:port# the page says http Error 403.14 Forbidden - the web server is configured to no list the contents of this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the *.svc file and click on "Set As Start Page" then press F5.